# Leaking injectors

Tags: fuel-injectors

How long would it take to damage a diesel motor where oil is diluted heavily with diesel,due to leaking injectors,engine made clunking sound and masses of black smoke poured from exhaust, service centre that were responsible for leaving injectors loose have done check on engine and are telling me it's fine,which I find doubtful as car was driven for 7 weeks before it billowed smoke and knocking and clunking occurred

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! I'm not quite sure I understand where your question is going. It sounds more like a rant against the service center than a real question about your vehicle. You aren't stating what kind of vehicle it is, so we can only surmise. Remember, too, diesel, while used as a fuel, is just a combustible oil. It will provide some amount of lubrication properties, though not what you're looking for in your motor oil. Suggestion is to change the oil and see if the knocking goes away. If it wasn't spewing black smoke all along, I'd also suggest it's not related